# Update Database on 2 Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to make a Clone server Like Server A and Server B

Ex :

After I'm making update in Server A data then on Server B is Sync Automatically or Programatically with Server A. When update Stored Procedure on Server A the server B is Sync.

is it possible ?

I don't want an answer like Backup then Restore.

Comment: I have seen similar questions to this on SO, and the usual answer is that you _could_ do this, but there are many caveats.  Take a simple one, what happens when you do a CRUD operation on one database and it fails on the second.  Do you rollback everything?  Do you keep trying on the second database?  Etc.  you can see where this is going.

Comment: The best option for you is to use always on feature of sql server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah I already search everywhere for an answer but all of them is same...
if the second one fail it pop up a notification.

Comment: @RanjanaGhimire Backup and restore ?

Comment: @Shiroze Instead of having 2 duplicate databases, would it be possible for you logically/physically _partition_ your current database?  E.g. you have some users from the west, and some from the east, and each has a separate database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's work for now, it's hard to export the data from west and import them into east.
because west didn't have an databases expert. center of all database stored in east server

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL server replication.

More information you can refer

[SQL Server Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An other option could be using [**Mirroring on SQL Server**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx) although it will not be continued on feature versions of SQL Server.
Please note that the secondary database is readonly copy of the principal database in mirroring.

If you have plans for versions after SQL Server 2016, you can think of using  **Always On Availability Groups**